# IE 9 table spacing issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The issue is that for some reason when in IE 9 (non-compatibility mode) one of the tds cause a goofy alignment.  In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2x3k3y5e/1/ the leftside button is fine it is the first of the right side buttons.  For some reason it will not set on the right side.  This is a part of user control (button bar) that will create various buttons for a page. ONLY in IE 9 have we noticed this issue.  I would like to fix it everywhere and was hoping to use some css for this.

```
<table style="margin-top:10px;" cellspacing="0" cellPadding="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td noWrap="nowrap">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 100%;">
            <input style="width: 125px;" id="BottomButtonBar_btnDelete" class="btnEntry"  name="m$c$PatientSearchUC$PanelSearch$PanelSearch_BBB$BottomButtonBar_btnDelete" value="Previous Criteria" type="button"/>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 4px;">
            <input style="font-weight: normal; " id="BottomButtonBar_btnUpdate" class="btnEntry"  value="Clear" type="button"/>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 4px;">
            <input style="width: 65px; font-weight: bold;" id="BottomButtonBar_btnUpdateAndReturn" class="btnPrimary btnEntry" value="Search" type="submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
    .btnEntry, .btnNav, .btnPrimary, .btnDefault{
  text-transform: none;
  cursor: pointer;  
  padding-right: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0; 
  color: #000000;
  min-width:60px;
  }

.btnNav {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
}

.btnEntry {
  background-color: #ccc;
  /*border: #b2b2b2 1px solid;*/
   border: #ababab 1px solid;
    color: #404040;  
    min-width:60px;
}
.btnDefault {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: #ababab 1px solid;
    color: #404040;
}
.btnPrimary {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #82a83d;
}
```

If I set the size it is fine, but I don't think that using jquery to reset the size of a button to it's same size is a good solution.  Again I am hoping there is some css trick that I don't know about to fix this. Thanks.

Side Note: I use IETester or a VM with Windows and IE 9

Comment: The fix I have right now I absolutely loathe is http://jsfiddle.net/2x3k3y5e/4/ which I plan on putting inside an isIE(9) check.

Answer (score 0):

Try Float:right:

HTML:

```
<table style="margin-top:10px;" cellspacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td noWrap="nowrap">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 100%;">
                <input style="width: 125px;" id="BottomButtonBar_btnDelete" class="btnEntry"  name="m$c$PatientSearchUC$PanelSearch$PanelSearch_BBB$BottomButtonBar_btnDelete" value="Previous Criteria" type="button"/>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 4px;">
                <input style="font-weight: normal; " id="BottomButtonBar_btnUpdate" class="btnEntry btnClear"  value="Clear" type="button"/>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 4px;">
                <input style="width: 65px; font-weight: bold;" id="BottomButtonBar_btnUpdateAndReturn" class="btnPrimary btnEntry" value="Search" type="submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.btnEntry, .btnNav, .btnPrimary, .btnDefault{
  text-transform: none;
  cursor: pointer;  
  padding-right: 0;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0; 
  color: #000000;
  min-width:60px;
  }
.btnClear{
    float:right;
}
.btnNav {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: #ccc 1px solid;
}
.btnEntry {
  background-color: #ccc;
  /*border: #b2b2b2 1px solid;*/
   border: #ababab 1px solid;
    color: #404040;  
    min-width:60px;
}
.btnDefault {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: #ababab 1px solid;
    color: #404040;
}
.btnPrimary {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #82a83d;
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing I did.  That works, don't get me wrong.  But I need to be able to do this on a hundred different pages.  Of those pages I am not sure which button to apply btnClear to.

Comment: Well, I created a new seperate class as you have one button with a left align property.. if you put the float:right; within the global class it woud 'mess-up' the other left-aligned buttons...

if you have hundreds of pages, surely you could place this as a template script? or run a string script find all buttons with the id of 'X' and replace the class with class." btnClear"?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean by a template script. But as far as keying off Id's I can't do that because the id's are created dynamically this just happens to be a page with simple id's.

Comment: What environment are you working with? ...is it CMS (if so which platform)... is it a bootstrap model... which one?... ember? code ignitor? etc...

Comment: It is a website using asp.net we have are using bootstrap.  But I don't see how that is relevant question when it can be replicated in jsfiddle.  This is an IE9 issue.

Comment: You said: "But as far as keying off Id's I can't do that because the id's are created dynamically" ...why not go to where they are created and edit the code?

Comment: The dynamic ids are to ensure there aren't two same ids on a page.  I don't really like the idea of tinkering with that.  Even to ensure static ids for button bars. If there are multiple button bars on a page that could spell danger.